# Copying files from a path with %~dp0% does not work

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Note that I am **wrong in assuming that I should use** `%~dp0%` to get the path excluding the filename of a batch file from inside it. I am leaving the question as-is as I have seen others with the same faulty premise. See the accepted answer, and its comment, for more information.

---

As a lot of the more advanced Windows users' know the expression `%~dp0%` in a batch file will be evaluated to the batch file's directory *including* the trailing backslash.

If I have a batch file in `D:\` containing `echo %~dp0%`, that line will behave as expected and output `D:\`.

**The problem**

If I create a file `D:\FILETOCOPY.txt` and a batch file `D:\problem.bat` with following contents:

```
@ECHO OFF

copy D:\FILETOCOPY.txt %userprofile%\FILECOPIEDA.txt

copy %~dp0%FILETOCOPY.txt %userprofile%\FILECOPIEDB.txt

set Evaluated=%~dp0%FILETOCOPY.txt
copy %Evaluated% %userprofile%\FILECOPIEDC.txt

cmd.exe
```

I get this output when I run it (by double clicking) on it:

```
        1 file(s) copied.
The system cannot find the path specified.
        1 file(s) copied.
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

D:\>
```

And the file `%userprofile%\FILECOPIEDB.txt` is missing from the destination. It does work, as proven by `FILECOPIEDC.txt`, if I evaluate the `%~dp0%` on a separate line. It seems that it messes up the file copy somehow, but it works as expected in the middle of a echoed line.

*Exactly* what is going on here?

Comment: Change the three calls to `copy` to `echo` instead, and run the batch file. Look carefully at the output, particularly of the second `echo`. Do you see two separate statements (like the first and third)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `%~dp0` not `%~dp0%`.

Your command translates to (brackets and underscores inserted for clarity)

```
copy [%~dp0]_[%FILETOCOPY.txt %] userprofile_[%\FILECOPIEDB.txt]
```

and since the variable `%FILETOCOPY.txt %` does not exist, it will be replaced by an empty string.

Comment: That works, and I understand the evaluation you described if the last percentage sign in `%~dp0%` shouldn't be there. But could you please add a line explaining why the second `%` is wrong? I was under the impression that variables in batch files were always surrounded by `%`-signs.

Comment: @kyl: %0 is a command-line argument substitution, not an environment variable substitution.  The syntax is different.

Answer (score 3):

Two `\\` in succession are treated as a single `\` in Windows.  It's not a problem.

If your %userprofile% contains spaces or `&` then surround the entire term in double quotes.

The other point has been mentioned - the term should be `%~dp0`